# Particle for どこ+住む

Tags: particle-に, particle-で

I have a question regarding the choice of particle in the following sentence in Genki I (p. 177):

お姉さんはどこに住んでいますか。

Why is に a better choice of particle here instead of で? Has it got to do with the verb 住む?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Per